# What does Hinduism say about Mental Disorders? How do we overcome them?

Tags: mind, health

For example in my case:

1. Serious and self-conscious most of the times.
2. Problem maintaining eye contacts and talking to people.
3. Lack of close relationships.
4. I often have a sense of "what is all this thing called life" thoughts even at home.

According to some scholars I have heard, *mind* is just a bunch of *thoughts*. So in that sense there is nothing like Mental Disorders. Disorders just mean that your thought patterns are aligned in a certain way.

However, does Sanatana Dharma actually say about dealing and overcoming such personality disorders? Does anyone have any experience with such problems?

I have started practicing Yoga and Pranayama but I don't see it is making me funny or anything like that!

Comment: Swami Vivekananda said - we are all mad; some of us are just better at hiding it than others

Comment: The accepted answer  not at all discusses what scriptures say about mental disorders. It's like a flyer for International yoga day.  Answer only tells about Pranayama.Pranayama what people do these days and how it should be done are totally different.  Proper guidance,care & years of practice is required to do yoga & pranayama and to apply it for curing purpose. Don't accept any answer very quickly. Take a [tour](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of help centre. See "When to [accept](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)" I suggest you to unaccept the answer.

Comment: Thank You @SreeCharan. Is it fine to do Yoga and Pranayama without Guidance? I am just following what my parents said and Baba Ramdev's instructions.

Comment: @Nishant It's fine to do simple Pranayamas (like Kapalbhati, Anulom Vilom etc...) without Guidance also... but advanced Pranayamas requires guidance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hindu way of life, the best treatment for mental disorders is **Yoga and meditation.**

Not only for mental disorders, but it also treats many of out illness and also help to improve concentration, make us feel relaxed etc.

I would like to mention 10 advantages here from the site

1- It lowers oxygen consumption.
2- It decreases respiratory rate.
3- It increases blood flow and slows the heart rate.
4- Increases exercise tolerance.
5- Leads to a deeper level of physical relaxation.
6- Good for people with high blood pressure.
7- Reduces anxiety attacks by lowering the levels of blood lactate.
8- Decreases muscle tension
9- Helps in chronic diseases like allergies, arthritis etc.
10- Reduces Pre-menstrual Syndrome symptoms.

You can see more here : http://ineedmotivation.com/100-benefits-of-meditation/

Adding from comment : Pranayamam is a good practise to purify our blood, to get a good mental strength, etc. (Thanks @Nishant for this point which I forgot.)

Comment: What about Pranayam?

Comment: The answer is not at all specific, but a general, rudimentary type answer. More specification, like the nature of mind, how certain postures or breathing exercises, or mantra chanting, or concentration exercises help in alleviating certain thought patterns, as well as references which detail those, will make the answer good.

Comment: And moreover, the OP asks specifically for mental disorders, so physical disorders part might not have been stated.